# how to accept real time input from user

Tags: input, protractor, real-time

I am trying to automate my application testing using protractor. While logging in the application, I have a step where I need to enter the pass-code I received in my mobile. I am trying to use 'prompt' command of javascript to accept passcode from tester in realtime. But I am getting an error

> "ReferenceError: prompt is not defined".

How can I solve this?

Are there another ways in whichШ can accept real time user input from tester.

commnad used :

```
prompt('Enter the passcode from your mobile', '')
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. Thank you.

Comment: This is an interesting question, I tried something along the lines of `await browser.executeScript("return prompt('please enter a value')");` but have not been able to get it working as I expected

Comment: Does this passcode change over a short period of time?

Comment: yes.every time i login i will receive a new pass-code which i need to enter. the login process is like.
1. I need to give my user id and password and click login button
2. A new page will be displayed asking me to select where i want my pass-code to be sent (mail/mobile)
3. A new page will be displayed asking me to enter the pass-code i received (through mail or mobile)

Comment: My Code                  :
element(by.name("username")).sendKeys('XXXXX');
element(by.name("password")).sendKeys('XXXXX');
element(by.buttonText('Sign In')).click();
browser.wait(EC.urlcontains'XXXX',9000);
element(by.linkText("Send passcode to my mobile phone")).click();
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.id("otppswd"))),9000).then (function(){
  prompt('Enter the passcode from your mobile', '').then(function(passcode){
     element(by.id("otppswd")).sendKeys(passcode);
     element(by.buttonText('Submit')).click();
     })
})

Comment: @sweatha just a quick tip for future, when you want to reply to a comment if it useful to tag that user in the comment like I have done. If you do they will receive  notification (when you posted the question you always get notifications anyway). I posted an answer but I can see from your comment that the second option I suggested will not work

Comment: @sweatha Have you had a chance to look at my answer yet? Let me know if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to get a version of the functionality you are working, in both async/await and promise manager approaches.

**Option 1 - getting value from browser prompt (async/await)**

```
  let getValueFromUserViaPrompt = async() => {
      await browser.executeScript("window.promptPasscode=prompt('Please enter your passcode','default')");
      //verify that the prompt is displayed
      await browser.wait(EC.alertIsPresent(), 3000, 'alert is not present');

      await browser.wait(async () => {
          try {
              //if alert is still present on page then return false so main browser.wait will check again.
              await browser.wait(EC.alertIsPresent(), 500);
              return false;
          } catch (err) {
              return true;
          }
      }, 30 * 1000, 'Alert has not been closed');

      //return the prompt value
      return await browser.executeScript("return window.promptPasscode");
  }

  console.log(await getValueFromUserViaPrompt());
```

**Added alternative using Promise manager**
Based on your comment I can see that you are using the promise manager so I have included an answer for that approach also. However, I would strongly advise moving over the async/await approach for your framework.

```
    let getValueFromUserViaPrompt = () => {
        browser.executeScript("window.promptPasscode=prompt('Please enter your passcode','default')");
        //verify that the prompt is displayed
        browser.wait(EC.alertIsPresent(), 3000, 'alert is not present');

        browser.wait(() => {
            //if alert is still present on page then return false so main browser.wait will check again.
            return browser.wait(EC.alertIsPresent(), 500)
                .then(() => false)
                .catch(() => true);
        }, 30 * 1000, 'Alert has not been closed');

        //return the prompt value
        return browser.executeScript("return window.promptPasscode");
    }

    getValueFromUserViaPrompt().then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
```